# Bootstrap Modal not firing after dynamically creating it with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I am pulling items from SP2013 and building the modal dynamically via ajax from a list. The id to trigger the modal is being dynamically retrieved from the ID column and all the items are built in the DOM but the Modal is not triggered. The console is not giving me any errors so I am not sure what is going on. I am also building the button that is supposed to trigger the modal and its ID is being pulled from the same column as the modal ID column.

```
var buildManagersCards = function(items) {
var managersContent = $("#managersContent");

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
//build cards
var managersCards =
'<div class="content col-md-6"><div class="single-news mb-4"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="view overlay rounded z-depth-1 mb-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="' + items[i].Image.Url +'" alt="' + items[i].Title + '" /><a><div class="mask rgba-white-slight waves-effect waves-light"></div></a></div></div><div class="col-md-9"><p class="font-weight-bold dark-grey-text">' + items[i].Title +
'</p><div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><div class="col-11 pl-0 mb-3 managerDescription"><div class="dark-grey-text ">' + items[i].Description+'<a data-toggle="modal" data-target=#basicExample'+items[i].ID+'><span class="modalButton" >Read More</span></a></div></div><a data-toggle="modal" data-target=#basicExample'+items[i].ID+'><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right modalArrow"></i></a></div></div></div></div></div>'; 
managersContent.prepend(managersCards);
}

};

var buildModal = function(items) {
var modalContent = $('#modalContent');

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
var modalContentCard = '<div class="modal fade" id=#basicExample'+items[i].ID+'  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"  role="document"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><strong>' + items[i].Title +
'</strong></h5><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div><div class="modal-body"><h5>Personal:</h5><p><strong>A dream I have is to:</strong> '+ items[i].Dream +'</p><p><strong>You’d be surprised to learn that I:</strong>'+ items[i].Learn +'</p><p><strong>My motto is:</strong>'+ items[i].Motto +
'</p><p><strong>The mission of our agency is:</strong>'+ items[i].Mission +'</p><hr><h5>Our current priorities are:</h5><p>'+ items[i].Priorities +'</p><h5>Our biggest accomplishments in the past year include:</h5><p>'+ items[i].Accomplishments +'</p><div class="agency"><h5>One thing you did not know about our agency is:</h5><p>'+ items[i].Agency+'</p></div></div></div></div></div>';
modalContent.prepend(modalContentCard);
console.log(modalContentCard);
}

};

//ajax call
var url1 =
"/ManagersMoments/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('managersMoments')/items";
var handle_ajax = function(url) {
$.ajax({
url: url,
method: "GET",
headers: {
Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose"
},
success: function(data) {
var items = data.d.results;
console.log(items);

buildManagersCards(items);
buildModal(items);

},
error: function(data) {
console.log("Error: " + data);
}

});

};

handle_ajax(url1);
```

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExample17"><span class="modalButton">Read More</span></a>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="#basicExample17" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><strong>Test</strong></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h5>Personal:</h5>
        <p><strong>A dream I have is to:</strong></p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Test<br /></p>
        <p></p>
        <p><strong>You�d be surprised to learn that I:</strong></p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Test<br /></p>
        <p></p>
        <p><strong>My motto is:</strong></p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Test<br /></p>
        <p></p>
        <p><strong>The mission of our agency is:</strong></p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Test<br /></p>
        <p></p>
        <hr />
        <h5>Our current priorities are:</h5>
        <p></p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Test<br /></p>
        <p></p>
        <h5>Our biggest accomplishments in the past year include:</h5>
        <p></p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Test<br /></p>
        <p></p>
        <div class="agency">
          <h5>One thing you did not know about our agency is:</h5>
          <p></p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Test<br /></p>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you remove the # from your modal id attribute it should work. I.e. `id="basicExample...”`

Comment: @Cue it worked.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have added your modal ID as:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="#basicExample17" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

It should be like:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicExample17" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

When you use `<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExample17">` if finds the html element with the id provided in `data-target` and then it will show that element on the screen.